# Duality and 1 forms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

How is a dual map defined if we are talking about partial derivatives and 1 forms?

Comment: What is your question? What are the $e^i$?

Comment: 1 forms @ACuriousMind and my question is if I can write the dual of the vector like that. Sorry I deleted my previous coment for it was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dual is defined by the map

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} \mapsto g_{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\nu$$

and hence the dual of $a \partial_t + b \partial_1$ is only $a \mathrm{d}x^t + b \mathrm{d}x^1$ iff the metric is Euclidean flat in the $t,1$-direction.

Note: Do not write "$X=$" if you mean the dual of $X$ is equal to something. Duality/equivalence is *not* equality, a 1-form is still a different object from a vector field.

Comment: and do you mean here that your $dx^1$ is my $e^1$ let us say? And do you also mean that if the metric was off diagonal then this is not the case. Say, we have $g_{t1}=1$ where everything else is zero then this would be equal to $dx^t$ rather than $dx^1$? @acuriousmind

Comment: I don't know how you defined your $e^i$, but since $e$ is usually used for canonical basis vectors, and the canonical basis vectors of the dual space are also usually denoted $\mathrm{d}x^i$, those should be the same. If the metric is off-diagonal as you say (and the diagonal entries are zero), then the dual of $\partial_t$ is $\mathrm{d}x^1$, and that of $\partial_1$ is $\mathrm{d}x^t$.